# How to get the name of variable

Tags: javascript

I have

```
let name = 'enzo'
let age = 20
```

if I log name `console.log(name)` and age `console.log(age)`, it will show

> enzo
>   20

but I expected to this effect

```
console.log("name:",name)
console.log("age:",age)
```

it will show

> name: enzo
>   age: 20

so how can I get the name of variable?

Comment: You already seem to know the names of your variables. It's very unclear what you're asking

Comment: Maybe he is asking how to get the name at runtime, I guess?

Comment: How do you plan to use the variables at all if you don't know their name?

Comment: It looks like you answered your own question with this code?
  `console.log("name:",name)`   I'm confused what you're asking.

Comment: Xinyang Li is right, I want to get the variable name at runtime!!

Answer (score 7):

One option is to use [shorthand property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015) in object initializers:

```js
let name = "enzo";
let age  = 20;

console.log({name});
console.log({age});
```

Does that solve your problem?

Comment: This is clever!  I'm gonna start doing this.

Comment: Very clever indeed.